# Intercepting requests made with Zombie.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, intercept, zombie.js

*Preamble: I'm trying to follow TDD methodology on my project while being new to Node.js in whole and Zombie.js in particular.*

I have an "all AJAX" HTML page I load with Zombie.js. That page performs few XMLHttpRequest queries to my server, and loads few JS files via `<script>` tags with GET arguments to them (JS files are generated on fly). However, starting server, all the supplementary stuff, resetting states of all these is very expensive, and keeping track of autogenerated JS files is complex to implement, so I want to essentially mock communication server without page noticiting.

One approach I've thought about is replacing `XMLHttpRequest` with hook object of my own via `browser.evaluate()`, but using this way I gain no control over how browser does any other requests, like for `<script src="/foo.js?magic=quux">` or `<img src="/tracker.gif?key=foobar">`.

Second approach is to redirect whole browser instance through proxy, and implement proxy of my own — that would suffice, but I'd prefer not to implement full-pledged HTTP(S) proxy for testing purposes only, as I'll end up testing proxy, and this won't end easily :)

So, is there other solution, maybe, that will give me precise control about what is Zombie.js telling to outer world and what does world answer?

Comment: As for your last point, you can use http://www.telerik.com/fiddler and do MITM changes to your requests and responses. It's a great program.

Comment: Isn't fiddler just a standalone application? I'm aiming for automated solution for testing purposes, and I don't see way to integrate fiddler in this workflow.

Comment: Yes, If you're looking for what req/res and want to edit them real time, it's a good tool. I have misunderstood your intent though.